# Who exactly is the "one guy" here?

Tags: dc, batman, the-batman

In *The Batman* (2022), Carmine's bodygaurds prevent Bruce Wayne from attacking Carmine:

> Carmine: Hey, watch it, fellas. You got the prince of the city there.
> Some event, huh? Brought out **the one guy** in the city more
> reclusive than me.
>
> Bruce Wayne: Thought you'd never leave the Shoreline. Aren't you
> afraid someone'll take a shot at you?

Who exactly is the "one guy" here?

Comment: Who do you *think* it could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's Bruce that he's referring to. Bruce was apparently notably reclusive in the film, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_(film)):

> Reclusive billionaire Bruce Wayne, who has operated for two years as the vigilante Batman, investigates the murder alongside the Gotham City Police Department (GCPD).